# addCustomOption disappears when updating cart item

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a function that programmatically adds a product to the the cart.  I'm adding a custom option to that product using addCustomOption:

```
$id = 27;
$qty = 2;

$new_custom_option = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(5, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)); //Makes the product unique
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$_product->addCustomOption('my_new_custom_option',$new_custom_option);

//I'm omitting the part where I set the $options_array

$params = array(
    'product' => $id,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'options' => $options_array,
);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$cart->init()->getQuote();

$cart->addProduct($_product, new Varien_Object($params));
$cart->save();
```

Then, I have another function that updates the cart item with new options:

```
$params = array(
    'product' => $_product_id,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'options' => $new_options_array,
);

$item->save();
$cart->updateItem($itemId, $params);
$cart->save();
```

The problem is that updating the cart item in this way removes my 'new_custom_option' from the item.  Can anyone tell me how to either maintain 'new_custom_option' or re-add it to the item when updating? I assume I have to add 'my_new_custom_option' to the options array, but I can't figure out how to do this.  addCustomOption seems to create a different kind of custom option that doesn't fit into the array.

The whole reason I'm doing this is to create a unique product, so I can have two identical items exist in the cart as separate entities.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are reseting custom options:

```
$params = array(
    'product' => $_product_id,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'options' => $new_options_array, //HERE
);
```

So you must recover the original custom options and then merge them with the new ones, something like that:

```
$oldOptions = $item->getProduct()->getCustomOptions()
$params = array(
    'product' => $_product_id,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'options' => array_merge($oldOptions, $new_options_array)
);
```

Perhaps you should map or convert to array $oldOptions (i'm not sure in which format are retrieved)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  Array_merge and setting ('options' => $oldOptions) throw error "Please specify the product required option." I feel that $_product->addCustomOption creates a different type of custom option.  Also, $item->getProduct()->getOptions() and $item->getProduct()->getCustomOptions() return different option ids.  Only the id value from $item->getProduct()->getOptions() works to update the options. My addCustomOption option does not appear in $item->getProduct()->getOptions(). There must be another way to update options added with addCustomOption.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up on this.  I couldn't figure out how to update or preserve these addCustomOptions in the cart:

```
$_product->addCustomOption('my_new_custom_option',$new_custom_option);
```

Instead I am just removing the item from the cart and adding a new one with the new options.